# Dired dead long - GUI Emacs Windows

Tags: gui-emacs

As suggested in the title, I use a GUI version of Emacs (25.3) on Windows. 
To be precise : Emacs 25.3.1 X86_64-w64-mingw32

Things were working perfectly but for a few days, some actions related to Dired like `C-x d` or `^` take literally ages (it's freezing like 15 seconds) which is a real pain. Emacs startup is fine.

I reinstalled Emacs totally but still get the issue. Any idea what is going wrong ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use ntemacs or cygwin-emacs? That can make a big difference. The best is to cite the full output of `M-x emacs-version RET`. It may be that the anti-virus software is the culprit.

Comment: @Tobias, sure I've edited my question

Comment: FWIW, a literal age is millions of years :)

Comment: What does `M-: (featurep 'ls-lisp)` say?  What is the value of `ls-lisp-use-insert-directory-program`? Note, that the slow startup of new processes under Windows may have an influence. Therefore, we could try the lisp version of `ls`.

Comment: Can you isolate the behaviour to specific directories? Or is it worse/better with certain directories than it is with others? If you can find consistent aspects to the issue, it may help to diagnose it.

Comment: Are you viewing remote directories in dired via tramp?